# UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, uipresentationcontroller

I'm new to swift and trying to understand how to use `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

What I need in my app is that when a button is pressed a popover from the button of the screen will be shown on with an **xib** file on half of the screen . 
What happens now is that I manage to segue to the second view controller but don't know how to load the **xib** file and how to make the popover to be an half of the screen from the button. this is my code

```
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController , UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func moveToPopoverView(sender: UIButton) {
      var popoverViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popover") as! UIViewController
      popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
      popoverViewController.preferredContentSize   = CGSizeMake(200, 200)

      let popoverPresentationViewController = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController

      popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
      popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self

      presentViewController(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()       
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is via a storyboard popover presentation segue.  It will handle the presented view controller instantiation for you.

1. Add a popover presentation segue to the button that will present the popover.  Give the segue an identifier.  This will handle anchoring the popover to the button:

[image: Popover presentation segue from (titleView) button]

2. Set the storyboard presentation details for the presented view controller.  I've selected **Page Sheet** presentation for a tableView controller (that's embedded in a navigation controller).

[image: (Page sheet) presented view controller]

3. Add the `prepareForSegue:sender:` code to pass any parameters to your presented view controller.  (I haven't learned Swift... sorry for the Objective C.)

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)__unused sender {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showBIBLESelectBookChapter"]) {
            UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
            if ([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[BIBLESelectViewController class]]) {
                BIBLESelectViewController *selectViewController = (BIBLESelectViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
                selectViewController.initialBookChapterVerse = self.bookChapterVerse;
            }
            UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverPresentationController = navigationController.popoverPresentationController;
            popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
        }
    }
```

The segue will do all the actual work for you, instantiating, presenting, and anchoring the popover view controller.

[image: Presented popover view controller]

You should be able to set your content size so your popover is half-screen.